# wrong error message output in function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate a Poperty value and down payment. The conditions are as follows:

property value:

Must be present
Must be numeric - positive - whole number
Must be at least 65,000 dollars more that the down payment.

down payment:

Must be present
Must be numeric - positive - whole number
Must be at least 20% of the value of the property (propValue)

My function is (sort of) working. It doesn't pass all the validation tests. If someone can point me in the right direction as to how to improve this it would be greatly appreciated. My 2 functions for the down pay and value:

```
function propValueValidation(errMessages){

var propValueLength = document.mortgage.propValue.value.length;

var propValueNumber = isNaN(document.mortgage.propValue.value);

var propValue = document.mortgage.propValue.value;

var downPayPlus = document.mortgage.downPay.value + 65000;

if (!propValueLength) {
    errMessages += " Property Value is a required field";
    return errMessages;
}
    else if (typeof propValue === 'number') {
        var remainder = (propValue % 1);
        if(remainder != 0){
            errMessages += "Property Value must be a positive whole number";
            return errMessages;
        }
    }
    else if (propValue < downPayPlus){
        errMessages += "Property Value must be at least 65,000 greater than the down payment";
        return errMessages;

    }
    return errMessages;
}

//validate down pay

function downPayValidation(errMessages){

var downPayLength = document.mortgage.downPay.value.length;

var downPay = document.mortgage.downPay.value;

var propValueMin = document.mortgage.propValue.value * 0.2;

if (!downPayLength) {
   errMessages += "Down Payment is a required field";
    return errMessages;
}
    else if (typeof downPay === 'number') {
        var remainder = (downPay % 1);
        if(remainder != 0){
      errMessages += "Down Payment must be a positive whole number";
        return errMessages;
        }
    }
    else if (downPay < propValueMin){
      errMessages +="Down Payment must be at least 20% of the property value";
        return errMessages;

    }

    return errMessages;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label class="label">Property Value </label>    
        <input type="text" name="propValue" id="propValue" size="7" maxlength="6" >

        <br>

    <label class="label">Down Payment </label>    
        <input type="text" name="downPay" id="downPay" size="7" maxlength="6" >
```

when downpay is "1nn1" it will still submit the form for example. Thanks!

Comment: `document.mortgage.propValue.value` is a string, not a number.

Comment: Where is the code where you actually call these functions? Have you noticed that you're not using the `propValueNumber` value anywhere? Are you aware that the `isNaN` function is _not_ intended for checking whether a string value is numeric?

Answer (score 0):

you can use parseInt() to confirm its a number.

```
var tempVal = document.mortgage.propValue.value;
var propValue = parseInt(tempVal); // this will try to extract an integer from tempVal

if (tempVal != propValue.toString()) // if true, there were non-number chars or value is NaN
{
  errMessages += "Bad value, please enter an integer";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `isNaN` on string values (which input values are). Instead first convert such a string to number with `Number()` (or `parseFloat`, but `Number` will require the whole of the input to parse as number, while `parseFloat` or `parseInt` will accept strings that *start* with a number). Then call `isNaN` on that.

There is also a problem with the `if else` logic, because you have one branch for numeric data (where it will never get, because the `value` property of input elements is always a string), and an `else` on that to compare the amount with another amount. Yet for that last test the value must be numeric. So that test is in the wrong place.

Here is your first function's code with some alterations made:

```
function propValueValidation(errMessages){
    var propValue = document.mortgage.propValue.value;
    var propValueNumber = Number(propValue);
    var downPayPlus = propValueNumber + 65000;
    var genericMsg = ' property value was provided. Please provide a positive' +
               ' whole number, at least 65,000 greater than the down payment.\n';
    if (!propValue.length) {
        errMessages += 'No' + genericMsg;
    } else if (isNaN(propValueNumber)) {
        errMessages += 'A non-numerical' + genericMsg;
    } else if (propValueNumber % 1) {
        errMessages += 'A fractional' + genericMsg;
    } else if (propValueNumber < downPayPlus){
        errMessages += 'A too small' + genericMsg;
    }
    return errMessages;
}
```